# Reactjs How to update the component after store updates

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using nachos-ui in my react native application, the Switcher component

in my configScreen.js like so:

```
<Switcher
     onChange={((difficulty) => this.onLevelSelect(difficulty) )}
     defaultSelected={this.props.difficulty} >
     <TabButton value='medium' text='medium'  />
     <TabButton value='easy' text='easy'/>
 </Switcher>
```

and I have a reset button that resets the value of this.props.difficulty from the store.

everything works fine the store gets reseted and the value but the Switcher keeps indicating to the old value, unless i move to another screen then goBack to configScreen.js, at that time the change takes effect(ie: the value of defaultSelected indicates the store value.

Can someone guide me on how to use componentShouldUpdate or 
componentWillRecieveProps ??

action/index.js :

```
exports.changeLevel = (select) => {
      return {
            type: 'CHANGE_LEVEL',
            select
      }  

}

exports.resetGame = () => {
      return{
            type: 'RESET_GAME',
      }
}
```

reducer/index.js :

```
module.exports = ( state = {}, action ) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'RESET_GAME' : 

            return {
                ...state,
                difficulty: 'easy',
            }
        case 'CHANGE_LEVEL':
            return {
                ...state,
                difficulty: action.select
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

store/index.js :

```
import { createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist'; 

import reducer from '../reducer';

const defaultState = {
    difficulty: 'easy',

}


export const configureStore = (intialState = defaultState, action) =>{

    var store = createStore(reducer, intialState,compose(
        autoRehydrate()
    ));
    persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage});

    return store;

}
```

configScreen.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Card, CardItem,  Button, Icon, Left, Body } from 'native-base';
import { AdMobBanner } from "expo";
import DropdownAlert from 'react-native-dropdownalert';
import {changeLevel, reset, resetGame} from '../actions';
import {Switcher, TabButton, themeManager} from 'nachos-ui';
import { configureStore } from '../store';

const buttonTheme = themeManager.getStyle('TabButton');

const newButtonTheme = {
  ...buttonTheme,
  BUTTON_BACKGROUND:'#fff',
  BUTTON_BORDER_WIDTH:1,
  BUTTON_BORDER_COLOR:'#4bb29e',
  BUTTON_BORDER_RADIUS:5,
  BUTTON_HEIGHT:25,
  BUTTON_WIDTH: 10,
  BUTTON_FONT_COLOR:'black',
  BUTTON_FONT_SIZE:14,
  BUTTON_FONT_WEIGHT:'normal',
  BUTTON_FONT_FAMILY:'jf',
  BUTTON_SELECTED_BACKGROUND:'#4bb29e',
  BUTTON_SELECTED_FONT_COLOR:'white',
  BUTTON_SELECTED_BORDER_COLOR:'#4bb29e',

}
themeManager.setSource('TabButton', () => (newButtonTheme))

const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width / 12;


class AboutScreen extends Component {

  _goBack = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack(null)
  }

  onClose(data) {
    // data = {type, title, message, action}
    // action means how the alert was closed.
    // returns: automatic, programmatic, tap, pan or cancel
  }

  // RESET THE STORE HERE 
  onReset() { 
    this.gameReset() 
    console.log(configureStore().getState())
  }

  onLevelSelect(selected) {

    this.props.dispatch(changeLevel(selected))

  }

  gameReset() {
    this.props.dispatch(resetGame())
  }    

  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={{backgroundColor: 'white',}}>
          <Content>
            <Card>
            <CardItem>
                          <Switcher
                            onChange={((difficulty) => 
                             this.onLevelSelect(difficulty) )}
                            defaultSelected={this.props.difficulty}
                            >
                                <TabButton value='medium' text='medium'  />
                                <TabButton value='easy' text='easy'/>
                          </Switcher>
                     <CardItem>
                        <Button title='reset' onPress={() => this.gameReset()} />
            </Card>
          </Content>

      </Container>
    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    difficulty: state.difficulty,
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
      changeLevel: () => dispatch(changeLevel(this.props.difficulty))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AboutScreen)
```

Comment: How are you updating `difficulty` in your store? Are you using Object.assign?

Comment: @qasimalbaqali i just uploaded the code, please take a look.

Comment: Try maybe when assigning `difficult` in your reducer using Object.assign() like so `difficulty: Object.assign({}, action.select)`

Comment: @qasimalbaqali it did not fix the issue, even: 
difficulty: action.selected,  //reducer and action updated accordingly.                 
the UI didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `componentWillRecieveProps`, since it will be deprecated soon enough.
It will be replaced with [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) *(Note, doesn't work the same way as `componentWillRecieveProps`)*.

Also, if you are using it correctly you shouldn't have to use those lifecycle-methods because

1. [A Prop change will trigger a rerender](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/)
2. `componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps)'s` purpose is/was to [update state on props change](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html).

If you want more help, post more code :)

**Update**

*A few notes:*

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if(nextProps.difficulty !== this.props.difficulty ){
        this.setState({difficulty: this.props.difficulty})
    }
}
```

What are you trying to achieve here? It's quite dangerous to perform `this.setState({...});` here. Because you can [trigger an endless loop of rerenders](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/tapping_into_componentwillupdate.html). 
Also you are not doing anything but assigning components local state to what the old props is. And you are not using `this.state.difficulity` anywhere in the application. Effectively you are only triggering another rerender *(which will happen anyway)*.

*Also:*

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        changeLevel: () => dispatch(changeLevel(this.props.difficulty))
    }
}
```

You don't have access to `this` because it's outside class context. 
You need to take in `this.props.difficulty` *(although you are passing it selected)* as a parameter to the dispatch call. You are not connecting your `resetGame()` here, which you should do. Lastly try to use different naming inside dispatch:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        onDispatchChangeLevel: (difficulty) => dispatch(changeLevel(difficulty)),
        onDispatchResetGame: () => dispatch(resetGame())
    }
}
```

Then when you are dispatching changeLevel pass it `this.props.difficulty` and use the connected dispatch instead of `this.props.dispatch`:

```
onLevelSelect(selected) {
    this.props.onDispatchChangeLevel(selected)
}

gameReset() {
    this.props.onDispatchResetGame();
}
```

*Finally:*

I´m not sure about this one:

`<Switcher
    onChange={((difficulty) => this.onLevelSelect(difficulty) )}
    defaultSelected={this.props.difficulty}>`

Usually you `onChange` is passing an event and you are treating it like a difficulity string `easy`. But as I said, I don´t know how Switcher works.

Hope this will be useful, I think the error lies somewhere on what I've commented on. Otherwise I can have another look :)

Comment: So i just implemented the highlighted code from your post, I added different names in my dispatch call, added a selected value to the second 
(difficulty) : => dispatch.resetGame(difficulty), updated my reducer to: 
 difficulty : action.selected {//also tried Object.assign({}, action.select)}
nothing happens, the same behavior continues.

Comment: Try to  console.log this.props.difficulity in  configscreens render. Check if the prop behaves correctly

Comment: I created a button to log this.props.difficulty, when the screen is loaded the state is behaving normally, meaning logging after changing the value, it gives the correct value. I have another button to log the store, the value in the store is set to "easy" and even the first button log gives the correct value, yet the UI doesn't change?. Do you think the Switcher component from 'nachos-ui' causing this?

Comment: It's possible, I meant not having a button. I meant logging in the render. What about your component will update? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Actually i deleted that! failed to mention it in before, after implementing, the changes suggested by you

Comment: console.log(this.props.difficulty) in the render function reflects the correct value upon switching from easy to medium, all in all it behaves as expected when reseting the store value also

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the switcher component from nachos-ui.

react-native-element buttonGroup or built-in component solved the issue,

nachos-ui: v0.2.0-beta.1

react-native :forked version from facebook v27 
expo SDK :v28

Comment: Glad you found the answer, I was occupied during the rest of the weekend. 
Hope you learned something from my post anyways!

Comment: @JakobGöranThomasson thanks!, i actually did. thank you so much. this will be here for future reference, i will open an issue for nachos-ui/Switcher to fix the bug.